# Formatting scraped data from a Website (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a scraper using BeautifulSoup and Requests that scrapes the pages of a site to get match schedule (and result, if available). This is what I have so far:

```
    def getMatches(self):
        url = 'http://icc-cricket.yahoo.net/match_zone/series/fixtures.php?seriesCode=ENG_WI_2012' # change seriesCode in URL for different series.
        page = requests.get(url)
        page_content = page.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content)

    result = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'bElementBox'})
    tags = result.findChildren('tr')

    for elem in tags:
        x = elem.getText()
        print x
```

And these are the results I get:

```
Date &amp; Time (GMT)fixture
Thu, May 17, 2012 10:00 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies
3rd&nbsp;TESTA full scorecard will be available shortly.Venue: Edgbaston,    BirminghamResult: England won by 5 wickets
Fri, May 25, 2012 11:00 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies
2nd&nbsp;TESTClick here for the full scorecardVenue: Trent Bridge, NottinghamResult:     England won by 9 wickets
Thu, Jun 7, 2012 10:00 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies
1st&nbsp;TESTClick here for the full scorecardVenue: Lord'sResult: Match Drawn
Sat, Jun 16, 2012 9:45 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies
1st&nbsp;ODIClick here for the full scorecardVenue: The Rose Bowl, SouthamptonResult:     England won by 114 runs (D/L Method)
Tue, Jun 19, 2012 9:45 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies
2nd&nbsp;ODIVenue: KIA Oval
Fri, Jun 22, 2012 9:45 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies
3rd&nbsp;ODIVenue: Headingley Carnegie
Sun, Jun 24, 2012 12:00 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies
1st&nbsp;T20Venue: Trent Bridge, Nottingham
```

Now, I want to classify the data in some structured format. A list of dicts, each containing
information about a single match would be ideal. But I'm stuck on how to achieve that. The output strings in the result have characters like `&nbsp`, and the time is weirdly arrange like `AMEngland`. There's also the matter that If I split the string using the space character as delimiter, countries like West Indies, with 2 words, will be split, and there won't be any uniform way to parse that.

So is there a way I can uniformly parse this data, so I can get in the form. Kinda like:

```
[ {'date': match_date, 'home_team': team1, 'away_team': team2, 'venue': venue},{ same for match 2}, { match 3 }...]
```

I'll appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't very difficult to separate the date/time and the countries.  You could do the same for "Venue" and "Result".

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Sun, Jun 24, 2012 12:00 AMEngland&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies"
>>> match = re.search(r"\b[AP]M", s)
>>> s[0:match.end()]
'Sun, Jun 24, 2012 12:00 AM'
>>> s[match.end():]
'England&nbsp; vs &nbsp;West Indies'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess looking at HTML all day made me somewhat forget I could just use a simple regex. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) instead; it'll make this task a lot easier.

You define [items](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) to scrape from that site:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CricketMatch(Item):
    date = Field()
    home_team = Field()
    away_team = Field()
    venue = Field()
```

then define a [loader with XPath expressions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) to fill these items. Afterwards you can use these items directly, or [produce JSON output or similar](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html).

Comment: I was indeed going for scrapy, but the app I'm working on already uses BeautifulSoup for existing tasks, so I've been told not to use that.

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question, unfortunately. Also note that SO aims to have questions and answers generally useful, not just for individual cases, so I'll leave my answer in place.